# How to get foreign key value instead of key in grid view with searching and filtering in yii 2?

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii2

I have two tables `staff` with columns `id`, `name` and `attendance`. `staff_id` is used as foreign key in `attendance` table.

I want to display staff name in attendance gridview.

**Attendance** model:

```
public function getStaff()
{
        return $this->hasOne(Staff::className(), ['id' => 'staff_id']);
}

public function getStaffName() {
          return $this->staff->name;
}
```

and in index.php I used this code

```
     <?= GridView::widget([
            [
             'attribute'=>'staff_id',
            'value'=>'StaffName',
            ],
]); ?>
```

to get value of staff name. In this way I am getting staff name successfully but the problem is that when I make search for staff name in gridview it say "staff_id" should be integer as I define it as integer, but here I want to search name of staff instead of id.

How is this possible ? Thanks in advance

Comment: if you have defined a relation between them, simply state the name of the relation instead of columns name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this in search model

`$query->joinWith(['staff(relation name)']);`

And add below code at filter query.

`$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'staff.name', $this->staff_id])`

In `staff.name` that in `staff` is table name.

Comment: How do I can do this if table A doesn't has foreign key with table B? because my table using MyISAM engine. But the table A actually has a column that contain id of table B. Thanks

Comment: @Blackjack you need to just make function in your model with use of `$this->hasOne()` OR `$this->hasMany()`. like as `public function getStaff()
{
        return $this->hasOne(Staff::className(), ['id' => 'staff_id']);
}`

Answer (score 6):

You can use this code

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'staff.name',
    ],
]); ?>
```

OR use this code

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        [
           'attribute' => 'staff.name',
           'header' => 'Staff title'
           'value'=> 'function ($model, $key, $index, $grid){
               return $model->staff->name;
           }'
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

OR in your code you can use this

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    [
      'attribute'=>'staff_id',
      'value'=>'getStaffName()',
    ],
]); ?>
```

and for search you can watch this video [Searching Related Table Data](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fw6k3BEsCCE)

Comment: Thank's  problem solved. for search above video was quite nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use this code

1. relation in models
 public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Country::className(), ['id' => 'country_id']);
    }
2. in grid view
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'id',
            'state_name',
           // 'country_id',
         [
      'attribute'=>'country_id',
      'value'=>'country.country_name',
    ],
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
3. Search Models
   change country_id from integer to safe than change on search function

 public function search($params)
    {
        $query = State::find();
        $query->joinWith(['country']);
       $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);
        $this->load($params);
        if (!$this->validate()) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
        ]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'state_name', $this->state_name])
         ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'country.country_name', $this->country_id]);
return $dataProvider;
    }
```