# How to display foreign key value instead of key in grid view in yii 2?

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii2

Very new to yii, my question is similar to this question [How to get foreign key value instead of key in grid view with searching and filtering in yii 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156033/how-to-get-foreign-key-value-instead-of-key-in-grid-view-with-searching-and-filt)

I've also seen this wiki https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculatedrelated-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0#hh10

I'm not able to figure out what code goes where in the above replies.

I've following tables

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `customer_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`country_id` is the foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Grid view**

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'email:email',
        'first_name',
        'middle_name',
        'last_name',
        'country_id',
        [
            'class' => ActionColumn::className(),
            'urlCreator' => function ($action, Customers $model, $key, $index, $column) {
                return Url::toRoute([$action, 'id' => $model->id]);
             }
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

I'm able to show country's `id` in grid view. How do I show `country` instead of `id`?

[image]

Comment: FIgure out what construct in VII generates a `JOIN` or a subquery in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use $model instance to get $model value (I assume you defined this in your Customer model and revers method in the country model, also hope you have FK as well when you created your tables) :
**Customer**:

```
public function getCountry()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Country::class, ['id' => 'country_id]);
}
```

Then in your grid view:

```
...
[
    'attribute' => 'country_id',
    'label' => 'Country',
    'value' => function(Customer $model){
       return $model->country->country; // I'm surprised that for the field name you used the same field name as a model, it will be better NAME because it more relevant here 
    },
]
```

Comment: It worked thanks. The `getCountry` was already generated. I added the second part and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

The more native way is to specify `relation.attribute` via dot separator. The label and other data will be automatically retrieved from relation.

Assume that you already have model's relation `country`.

```php
    GridView::widget([
        // ...
        'columns' => [
            // Example 1. Just get label and value `as is` from relation
            'country.country'

            // Example 2. If you want custom output or label
            [
                'attribute' => 'country.country',
                'format' => 'html',
                'value' => function (Country $model) {
                    return '#' . $model->id . ' <strong>' . $model->country . '</strong>';
                },
            ],
        ],
    ]);
```